# Just installed Ubuntu but how do I get it to boot

Tags: windows-8

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my new HP-2326 PC which came with windows 8.  I installed Ubuntu from a CD.  I chose to partition my harddrive and keep Windows.  The install was successful but when I reboot It goes directly in Windows.  Can somebody please help?

P.S.  Here are the step I found to install Ubuntu from DVD.

Here are the steps I followed to get the pc to boot from the DVD drive:

1. At start of boot up I hit F10 to get to HP setup screen.
2. Then moved to right to SECURITY SCREEN.
3. Then down to SECURE BOOT CONFIGURATION.
4. At the red screen F10 to accept.
5. Then DISABLE SECURE BOOT and also DISABLE FAST BOOT.
   enable LEGACY SUPPORT.
6. Back to left to FILE, highlight SAVE CHANGES AND EXIT.
7. Reboot and then the pc boots from the DVD drive.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do use use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Boot repair is an application with repairs/reinstalls the GRUB2 boot menu, which allows you to choose between Ubuntu and Windows when your computer boots. As you do not have access to Ubuntu, you will want to create a Boot Repair USB, and boot from it to repair the boot menu.